# SHA1 Mismatches openssl

Tags: c++, openssl, sha1

I'm a Java developer porting a C app to Java. I'm not a c developer so this alone has been a challenge. Part of the software creates a SHA1 using openssl. I'm not able to achieve matching SHA hashes between C and Java. In fact, after distilling the implementations down to just a few lines of code and then testing them against openssl on ubuntu, ALL 3 produce different hashes for the same string.

I've been working on this for hours and I'm about to lose my mind. The C and Java implementations are below. PLEASE, if you see something I've done wrong, please point it out.

UPDATE: I've been able to get openssl cmd to match by adding a -n to echo. Apparently it automatically adds a line end. I'm still stuck on using it via C though.

JAVA

```
System.out.println(
org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha1Hex("symphony")
);
```

```
HASH: 1c882ecb4c9e6cf19a4ff207c7dbf8a250567fbf <- CORRECT SHA1
```

---

C++

```
uint32_t sha1_hash[5];
unsigned char data[] = "symphony";
SHA1(data, 8, (uint8_t *)sha1_hash);
cout << "SYMPHONY " << hex << sha1_hash[0] << sha1_hash[1] << sha1_hash[2] << sha1_hash[3] << sha1_hash[4]<< dec <<  endl;
```

```
HASH: e8b8a894e4f0b00c3b9f69ecfe81c1f0a3d43817
```

---

```
openssl cmd on ubuntu
echo symphony | openssl dgst -sha1
HASH: 4b2c22b662de79e609295798f6fc5cb5f7676fa6

openssl cmd on ubuntu
echo -n symphony | openssl dgst -sha1
HASH: 1c882ecb4c9e6cf19a4ff207c7dbf8a250567fbf
```

Comment: `cout << "SYMPHONY "` is not C.  tag removed.

Comment: The fact that you are a *java* developer doesn't mean that you should tag with [tag:java] because this is a c++ problem. There is a openssl constant for the size of the target buffer and it should be `uint8_t`.

Comment: You can debug SHA1 function in your C++ library, it's easier that way as we have no idea which implementation for SHA1 you are using.

Comment: As CLEARLY stated in my post, I'm using openssl's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `uint32_t sha1_hash[5]`

change this to `uint8_t my_hash[20]`

and print it using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
...

uint8_t my_hash[20];
SHA1(data, length, my_hash);
cout << hex;
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << (my_hash[i] & 0xFF) << " ";
}
```

Where `length` is presumably `strlen("symphony")`

Comment: Thank you. That works. Will you please explain a few things to me. I don't understand why we must perform the & 0xFF operation. Without it, I get garbage output. What is it doing? Also, what's happening when I use uint32_t instead of uint8_t? The hash is the correct size but obviously wrong. I'm not clear on why the hash is wrong and what's causing it. 

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `uint32_t` is for 32-bit integers (`unsigned int`) whereas `uint8_t` is for character `unsigned char`. `cout` has to decide on how to interpret the data, `0xFF` tells `cout` to treat data as positive integer between `0` to `0xFF` (`255`)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This was very helpful.